# Choosing database for full-text-indexing (SQL/NoSql)

Tags: sql, nosql, full-text-indexing

I'm searching for a good solution to build a large databased-full-text-index. Currently i'm using a Sybase iAnywhere Database for my full-text-index, but with a growing database it seems to be slow. Now i'm not sure, if this is a problem with relational databases or only sybase/my fault.

I searched also for nosql-solutions, but i can't decide which is the best one (MongoDB/CouchDB).

Now i have two question, is there a reason(technical) why sql or nosql databases are better for build large full-text-index?

Does anyone know a good nosql database for building a large full-text-index?
Maybe some one has experiances with them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) are much more feature-rich and high-performance solutions for fulltext search.

FWIW, CouchDB is [integrated with Lucene](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Full_text_search), the same engine at the core of Apache Solr.